# Unwanted/untracked files still in .git directory despite "git reset --hard HEAD~1"

Tags: git

I accidentally added a tmp directory with some large files to my (only) local git repository (the .git directory now has a too big size of 134 MB).

I looked how to "remove" this last commit and found the command `git reset --hard HEAD~1` and did it. If I run `git log` and look in gitk the last commit is indeed gone. But if I check the size of the .git directory again it still has the size of 134 MB. If I search for large files in .git/objects/ I find a file with the exact size of the video file. So it seems that the files of the deleted commit are still there. I want to remove this file in the .git directory. I already tried `git clean -n` but nothing is displayed to be deleted.

So my question is how to remove/clean/purge the .git directory from "unused" files.

Comment: The thing is that the revision you "reverted" (by resetting) is still being pointed to by other references, like reflog. It will stay there for a while and then it will eventually get garbage-collected. It can be forced, though, but I don't know the procedure for it.

Comment: `git-gc` seems to do it. It compresses the .git directory to 94 MB not matter if I did `git reset --hard HEAD~1` before. The pruning time (parameter --prune) is two weeks by default so the unwanted files may be removed in some time.

Comment: Running `git gc` without first expiring the old reflog entries leaves the large object in the repository, but compacts the repository in general.  Running `git gc --prune=now` *after* expiring the old reflog entries should get you a much smaller compacted repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want it gone immediately—it will go away on its own *eventually*, which is a lot easier—you must rid yourself of the reflog entries that [eftshift0 mentions in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52611602/unwanted-untracked-files-still-in-git-directory-despite-git-reset-hard-head#comment92157577_52611602).  There are likely exactly two: one for the previous value of `HEAD`, and one for the previous value of the branch that `HEAD` itself names.  In some cases, there may be more; rarely, there might be fewer.

To do this, use `git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all`.  Note that this will remove *all* unreachable reflog entries from *all* references plus `HEAD`.  The definition of *unreachable* here is the same as the one in [Think Like (a) Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52611602/unwanted-untracked-files-still-in-git-directory-despite-git-reset-hard-head#comment92157577_52611602): in this particular case "reachable" means "reachable from the current value of the reference itself".  This particular change cannot be undone, so you should be very sure you don't want any discarded commits back before doing this.

Once you have done that, run `git gc --prune=now` to remove the unreferenced commit and its unreferenced file.

Comment: Thanks. Good that it can be done manually but also that git would have cared about this unreferenced commits.